# How/why do moths appear to not move for days?

Tags: animal-behaviour, bugs, moths

I've noticed that there is a moth on the outside of my apartment door that has been just sitting there for two days now:

[image: Moth]

There is a light outside my apartment door that likely is what attracted this guy in originally, but even at night time, it just sits here.  This isn't the first time I've witnessed a moth do this before either.  How are moths able to do this, and why do they do this?

Comment: It it still alive? (Just to make sure ;-) )

Comment: @anderas it's gone now so I assume it flew away!

Comment: What has the temperature been in your area?

Comment: @EvanM Within the past 3 days, around 55 in the morning and warming up to around 70, then back down to 55ish for the night (Fahrenheit).

Comment: It could also be waiting for a mate, basically moth leaves cocoon, lays eggs and dies. The fact that the wings are spread leads me to believe it is a display to attract a mate.

Comment: White moth on black door = bird food.

Comment: @TimmyJim In that picture, the moth looks like different shades of beige. Is that what it was?

Comment: @Sue it was like a greyish color. The flash on my camera kind of ruined it's color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speculation based off general knowledge here but that looks to be a common gray moth. Based off some information I've pieced together, mating is usually spring to early summer. This leads me to believe the display you are seeing is for mating. These moths are found through out the nation but heavily concentrated in Ohio and Michigan.

Comment: I'm in southeast Virginia - but still I feel I've seen this kind of moth back when I lived in Pennsylvania.

Comment: @TimmyJim yea they are everywhere. http://mothphotographersgroup.msstate.edu/species.php?hodges=6590